# How to fetch domain names which carry exact TLD from MySQL table column?

Tags: mysql

In my `"domains"` MySQL table, I have a column `"domain_name"` which carries domain names e.g.

```
example.com, example.com.au, example.org, example.net, domain.com, etc.
```

I have a search textbox and some checkboxes with Top Level Domains (TLD).

I want to perform a search query that fetches domains from above table based on what is typed in search textbox and which TLDs are checked.

I know that I can search domains based on some characters typed in textbox with the help of following query:

```
SELECT * FROM domains WHERE domain_name LIKE '%" . $domain_name . "%'
```

But I can't find a proper way using that I can select only those domains with some specific TLD. Moreover multiple TLD checkboxes can be checked to find domains.

To find domain based on TLD selected, I tried following query:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(domain_name, '.', 2) LIKE '%.com%'
```

But it fetched `.com.au` domain too. Moreover, I can't use this query to check for different TLDs (may be using something IN() operator?).

So how can I find domains having characters `c` and TLD `.com` in domain name?

For multiple TLDS, I want to find domains having characters `c` and TLDS `.com`, `.com.au`, `.net`?

Answer (score 0):

The `%` is the wildcard operator. If you want to search for URLs ending with **.com**, then you can simply use

```
LIKE '%.com'
```

Note that removing the `%` at the end of the searched text explicitly tells the search engine that the string ends with **.com**.

Comment: No, I can't use `LIKE` and `%` etc. here because I don't know in advance that the TLD to look into the main string is `.com` or `.com.au`. Moreover, it can be multiple TLD to search for.

Comment: @Sachin what stops you from typing ```domain_name LIKE '%.com' OR domain_name LIKE '%.com.au'``` ?!

Comment: @Sachin "But it fetched .com.au domain too. Moreover, I can't use this query to check for different TLDs (may be using something IN() operator?)." The quote, taken from your question is a problem-statement, which states that ```SUBSTRING_INDEX(domain_name, '.', 2) LIKE '%.com%'``` will find .com.au results even when it's not needed. If you remove that wildcard from the end, then the problem from the quote is solved. If you use several LIKE operators, separated by OR, as described in my previous comment, then the problem from your comment here is solved as well.

Comment: I tried `SELECT * FROM domains WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(domain_name, '.', 2) LIKE '%.com' `, it still fetches `.com.au`, Why?

Comment: @Sachin because you do not need to call ```SUBSTRING_INDEX```. Try ```domain_name LIKE '%.com'``` instead.